# pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'). I can't determine a mistake

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

```
with connection:  
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Data change')
    window.geometry('500x300')
    title1 = input('Name of film: ')
    country1 = input('Country: ')
    year1 = int(input('Year: '))
    duration1 = int(input('Duration: '))
    clicked2 = input('Genre: ')
    clicked3 = int(input('Director ID: '))

    sql = """insert into Film(director_id, title, genre, year, country, duration_in_min) values((select * from Director where Id = %s),%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"""
    var = (title1, clicked2, year1, country1, duration1, clicked3)
    cursor.execute(sql, var)
    connection.commit()
```

I can't determine what exactly the error is in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following subquery in the values clause:

```
(select * from Director where Id = %s)
```

This subquery likely returns more than one columns, which triggrs the error message. You should select only 1 column, or just simply use the director id directly without a subquery.

The order of your parameters do not match the order of the fields in the fieldlist of the insert. For example, the first field in the insert is `director_id`, but you are passing `title1` parameter in the first position of your parameter array.

Comment: thank you, I fixed this error, it's working now.